# group similar documents

Tags: complexity-theory, information-retrieval, similarity

This question relates to grouping/clustering similar documents in Information Retrieval.

I have a set of documents, D1, D2, .. Dn. For each document, Di, I also have a set of keywords, Di_k1, Di_k2, ..., Di_km. Similarity between two documents, Di and Dj is given by a function that involves the related keywords i.e. similarity(Di, Dj) = f(Di_K, Dj_K).

Now, I want to place each of these documents into a set of groups/clusters such that each cluster contains similar type of documents for a given a threshold value of similarity between the elements present in a cluster.

One easy way is to look at every pair of pages possible which I obviously want to avoid because the number of documents I have is fairly large, in millions. I was going through the Introduction to Information Retrieval book but I don't find any scalable algorithm mentioned.

My question is what kind of algorithm can help me cluster the documents efficiently? I am specially interested in the computational complexity of the algorithm.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: please clarify what exactly are you looking for. finding optimal subsets is NP Hard, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. I know its hard and that's why I am looking for an efficient algorithmic solution that are better than the easiest but the slowest implementation possible.

Comment: since it is NP Hard, there is no known polynomical solution for this problem, you will have to iterate over all possible solutions and choose the optimal - this will be O(2^n) where n is the number of documents. there are some polynomical algorithms to find an approximation, but these are only heuristics, and might fail.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, *off the top of my head* ,you can use a Language model based approach . First , use machine learning to build a LM for each possible class. Say, a bigram LM. Then, for each new document you see, calculate P(new document| class) for all classes. Choose the one with the max probability. Use bayes rule to simplify the above formula

Answer (score 0):

One relax similarity between ALL document in the cluster.  Pick an arbitrary center and have similarity to center.

Complexity is

(n / avgClusterSize) * (n / 2)